# Is there a more efficient way to get a "future" result from a multithreaded procedure?

Tags: java, multithreading, future

I coded a program to find a given String in such a way, that it builds all possible strings (a, b, c, .., z, aa, ab) until it builds the given String in the input. The app uses 4 threads to work, when a thread doesn't find the String, it returns null in a `Future<String>`.

I have implemented a way to store the Futures, so I can access them, when the threads terminated, it seems overly complicated, but i don't know how i could do it better.

```
public class StringFinderApp {

    private static final String BENE = "bene";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int numberOfThreads = 4;
        System.out.println("Searching for solution using " + numberOfThreads + " threads");
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

        List<Future<String>> futures = new LinkedList<Future<String>>();
        Future<String> future = null;
        int lengthOfExpression = 1;
        while(future == null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                futures.add(executor.submit(new StringFinder(lengthOfExpression, BENE, i + 1)));

            }
            lengthOfExpression++;
            for(Future<String> f : futures) {
                try {
                    if(f.get()!=null) {
                        future = f;
                    }
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }

        }

        try {
            System.out.println("Result is: \"" + future.get() + "\"");
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        executor.shutdownNow();
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("breaking took : " + (end - start) + " miliseconds");
        System.out.println();


    }
}
```

Result:

Result is: "bene"
breaking took : 705 miliseconds

Comment: You should first define "better". What do you want to improve?

Comment: I am storing all the Futures in a LinkedList, even the null ones. After every iteration, I search for a not null element in the list, and if i find it, i have my result. This leads to having 15 null elements in the linked list, when I am searching for a 4 letter word. This seems like an overly complicated way for me, but i can't think of a better solution using futures.

Comment: Have you considered [Fork&Join](https://www.baeldung.com/java-fork-join)?

Comment: Have you considered using a [CompletionService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html)?

Comment: @Mangos, you don't have null elements in the list, because you store future results that haven't been resolved yet, machine "doesn't know" they will be null, only you do. If you don't like having seen and resolved empty results still in a list, you can try using a `Queue` and throwing away futures you no longer need.

Comment: `f.get()` will block till a there is a result for one thread of all, so somehow I would start a new code design from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

I think, `CompletionService` will do the job for you:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
CompletionService<String> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(executor);
// submit 4 Tasks to completion service
for(int i=0; i<4; ++i) {
    futures.add(completionService.submit(new StringFinder(lengthOfExpression, BENE, i + 1)));
}
// non-busy wait for the first future to complete
Future<String> f = completionService.take();
// print the result from the first finished future
System.out.println("Result is \""+f.get()+"\"");
// cancel the other threads b/c we are only interested in the result of the 'first finished thread'
futures.stream()
    .filter(fut -> f != fut)
    .foreach(fut -> fut.cancel(true));
// shutdown executor
executor.shutdown();
```